# How to plot graph using canvasJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, canvas, graph

**Here I try to plot a graph using dynamic data `inputs array data`**

But I'm getting some error in the console 
Error: `canvasjs.min.js:197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTime' of undefined`

```js
window.onload = function () {
function setObject(name) {
  this.y = name;
}
var inputs=[1,23,21,2,67,54]
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

  var cookieValue = inputs[i];
  var setObj = new setObject(cookieValue);
  arr.push(setObj);
}
plot1 = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
var plot = [{ "y":1},{ "y":23},{ "y":21},{ "y":2},{ "y":67},{ "y":54}]
var graph = [{
  type: "line",
    //when i try to use plot1 instead of plot then graph not showing
  dataPoints:plot
 }]

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 animationEnabled: true,
 theme: "light2",
 title:{
  text: "Simple Line Chart"
 },
 axisY:{
  includeZero: false
 },

 data: graph
});
chart.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

> When I try to use `dataPoints:plot1` then it's not working

`plot` and `plot1` have same data but Why it's happening?
am I using the wrong approach?
Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

Your variables `plot` and `plot1` are not equivalent. `plot` is an array, but `plot1` is a string. CanvasJS `dataPoints` option expects an array, so if you give it a string, it doesn't work.

I don't know why you decided to use `JSON.stringify()` here, which converts your `arr` to a string. Just use `arr` directly!

```
var graph = [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: arr
}]
```

Comment: As Hamsterrific mentioned, dataPoints is an array. Please refer [docs](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/) for more info.